# Webpack config: Conditionally import module

Tags: webpack, babeljs, eslint

So I want to do:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  import StatsPlugin from 'webpack-stats-plugin';
}
```

But eslint says:

```
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

I'm using babel-eslint parser.

Does this imply I can't load modules conditionally?

Comment: If you want to load modules conditionally, you should just disable this rule.

Comment: ES6 spec states this isn't possible. You could try a regular require instead.

Comment: Related, though not quite a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367532/how-can-i-conditionally-import-an-es6-module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic synchronous imports are not possible with ES2015 modules. It's only possible to import stuff dynamically with asynchronous imports via [`import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

Why don't you just import it and apply it conditionally?

```
import StatsPlugin from 'webpack-stats-plugin';

...

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(new Statsplugin())
}
```

Comment: If I import a module and don't refer to it anywhere in my code later (i.e. essentially include but not use), does webpack still include it in the bundle?

Comment: webpack 1 will still include it because CommonJS don't allow this kind of optimization, webpack 2 can remove unused functions when ES2015 modules are used. This feature is called tree-shaking.

Comment: @jhnns Can you include that comment in your answer? I was driven here by a similar situation, but it seems that with Webpack 2 the optimization is already being made.

Comment: @jhnns is there any way webpack 1 can exclude `require`d modules inside a conditional like `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { config.plugins.push(new require('webpack-stats-plugin')()) }`?  Seems like it would be possible...

Comment: When you write `if (PRODUCTION)` you can use the `DefinePlugin` to replace all occurrences of `PRODUCTION` into `false`. Webpack will not follow `require()` inside of dead code branches. Unfortunately, `if ("production" === "production") {` is currently not detected as dead code branch

Comment: This is really getting to be a problem with isomorphic JS.  Sometimes you need to conditionally use deps on the server that will break the webpack build for the client.

Comment: This is what `resolve.alias` is fixing in webpack. Furthermore, if you write small separate modules with their own `package.json`, you can use [the `browser` field](https://gist.github.com/defunctzombie/4339901) in order to switch entry points in your module.